# Converting dynamic, nicely formatted tabular data in Python to str.format()

Tags: migration, python-3.x, python

I have the following Python 2.x code, which generates a header row for tabular data:

```
headers = ['Name', 'Date', 'Age']
maxColumnWidth = 20 # this is just a placeholder
headerRow = "|".join( ["%s" % k.center(maxColumnWidth) for k in headers] )
print(headerRow)
```

This code outputs the following:

```
         Name          |        Date        |          Age
```

Which is exactly what I want - **the data is nicely formatted and centered in columns of width *maxColumnWidth***.  (maxColumnWidth is calculated earlier in the program)

According to [the Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-examples), you should be able to do the same thing in Python3 with curly brace string formatting, as follows:

```
headerRow = "|".join( ["{:^maxColumnWidth}".format(k) for k in headers] )
```

However, when I do this, I get the following:

```
ValueError: Invalid conversion specification
```

But, if I do this:

```
headerRow = "|".join( ["{:^30}".format(k) for k in headers] )
```

Everything works fine.
**My question is: How do I use a variable in the format string instead of an integer?:**

```
headerRow = "|".join( ["{:^maxColumnWidth}".format(k) for k in headers] )
```

Comment: "My question is: what am I doing wrong on this line:" What do you get that you don't like?

Comment: That's an amazingly different question.  I'm unable to follow the jump from the original question to this question.  I'm quite shocked.  "Edited for clarity" is false. It was revised to be utterly different.

Comment: @S.Lott - That's because it took me a while to figure out what I was really asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
headers = ['Name', 'Date', 'Age']
maxColumnWidth=21
headerRow = "|".join( "{k:^{m}}".format(k=k,m=maxColumnWidth) for k in headers )
print(headerRow)
```

yields

```
        Name        |        Date        |        Age
```

1. You can represent the width `maxColumnWidth` as `{m}`, and then
   substitute the value through a `format` parameter.
2. No need to use brackets (list comprehension) inside the `join`. A
   generator expression (without brackets) suffices.

Comment: Please note that generator expression do not need brackets around them only if they are the only argument used in a function. I thought it might be worth noted for those discovering generators so that they don't make the mistake to omit the brackets in the other cases and wondering why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

As it says, your conversion specification is invalid. "maxColumnWidth" is not a valid conversion specification.

```
>>> "{:^{maxColumnWidth}}".format('foo', maxColumnWidth=10)
'   foo    '
```